# Display error if field doesn't starts with specific number

Tags: javascript, html

I like do display an error if user entered a digit that does not start 22 or 27 or 06 etc. in javascript..

Here's my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>
<form name="form" action="action.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
<span>Mobile Number(Required)</span>
<input type ="integer" name="contact" id ="contact" 
 value="+639" maxlength="13"/>&nbsp;<label id ="errorEight"></label>
&nbsp;<label id ="errorAlphaFour"></label>
&nbsp;<label id ="errorMinThree"></label><br>
</HTML>

<javascript>
function validate()
{
    var valid = true;
    var numeric =/^[0-9+]+$/;

    if(contact.value=="")
    {
        document.getElementById('errorEight').innerHTML="*Field is empty";
        document.getElementById('errorAlphaFour').innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById('errorMinThree').innerHTML="";
        valid=false;
    }
    else if(contact.value!="" && contact.value.match(numeric))
    {
        document.getElementById('errorEight').innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById('errorAlphaFour').innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById('errorMinThree').innerHTML="";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('errorAlphaFour').innerHTML="*Invalid number";
        document.getElementById('errorEight').innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById('errorMinThree').innerHTML="";
        valid = false;
    }

    if(contact!="" && contact.value.match(numeric) && contact.value.length<13)
    {
        document.getElementById('errorAlphaThree').innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById('errorTwo').innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById('errorMinThree').innerHTML="*Minimum of 13 digits";
        valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
    }

    if(contact.value=="")
    {
        document.getElementById('errorEight').innerHTML="*Field is empty";
        valid = false;
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
</javascript>
```

what do i need to add to my code for it to display error if the user entered a number that doesn't start with 27 or 22 or 06 etc.

Comment: `if ( value.indexOf('22') === 0 ) error`

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work..

Comment: Indenting the code and adding empty lines between different if-then-else blocks makes it easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to perform a simple match test using a regular expression.

```
var regex = '/^22[0-9]*$|27[0-9]*$|06[0-9]*$/g';
if (contact.match(regex) == null)
{
    // Error display
    // Instructions....
}
```

Hope it helps,

NB: If you could please review your spelling and grammar before posting, it would help us help you !

Edit: http://regexr.com/3aofd

Comment: Yes, my bad tried to do the things quickly. I updated the regex try with the new one ;)